# Why wont my list appear using ionic?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

Everytime I try to display my list by using ionic serve I just get a blank screen? I've followed the tutorial step by step and still nothing?

my code in html for the list:

```
  <body ng-app="calorific" ng-controller="calCtrl">
<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
    <h1 class="title">Calorific</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
     <ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="todos in todo"{{todo.name}} </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

My JS:

```
app.controller('calCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.todo = [
    {name: 'apple'},
    {name: 'banana'},
    {name: 'pear'},
    {name: 'kiwi'},
    {name: 'kfc'}
    ]
 })


GET http://localhost:8100/css/style.css 
app.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined
ionic.bundle.js:19526 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'calCtrl' is not a function,    got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ng/areq?p0=calCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (ionic.bundle.js:7982)
at assertArg (ionic.bundle.js:9499)
at assertArgFn (ionic.bundle.js:9509)
at ionic.bundle.js:16350
at ionic.bundle.js:15518
at forEach (ionic.bundle.js:8250)
at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:15505)
at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:14997)
at publicLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:14876)
at ionic.bundle.js:9369ionic.bundle.js:19526 (anonymous    function)ionic.bundle.js:16476 $getionic.bundle.js:22421 $get.Scope.$applyionic.bundle.js:9367 bootstrapApplyionic.bundle.js:12104 invokeionic.bundle.js:9365 doBootstrapionic.bundle.js:9385  bootstrapionic.bundle.js:9279 angularInitionic.bundle.js:34044 (anonymous  function)ionic.bundle.js:10663 triggerionic.bundle.js:10933 eventHandler
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in your html. Shouldn't it be todos like so,

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="todos in todo">{{todos.name}} </ion-item>
```

I added a missing closing tag for ion-item as well. I'm not too familiar with Ionic so I just wanted to note that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference `todos` incorrectly.

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="todos in todo"{{todo.name}} </ion-item>
```

Use `todos` instead, as in `{{todos.name}}`:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="todos in todo"{{todos.name}} </ion-item>
```

Comment: Ive updated the post witht he error after using the dev tools on google

Answer (score 0):

Your `ion-item` is not closed. Also you're referencing `todos` as the singular item, when you're calling `todo.name` in the body.

First, I suggest your rename your scope variable to `$scope.todos` to use the correct plural form. Then reorder your `ng-repeat` to `todo in todos`. That is change

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="todos in todo"{{todo.name}} </ion-item>
```

to

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="todo in todos">{{todo.name}}</ion-item>
```

In addition to renaming `scope.todo` to `scope.todos`.